# How to redirect textfields enter command of going to form submit instead of button midway form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm using material UI as my component library. I have a small dialog that has a "recover password" button placed somewhere inside the form.  - I notice that after adding this button the "enter" command in the textfields becomes the onClick command of the buttons.

The form is simply like:

```
type PropTy = {
    classes: any,
    submit: (Event) => mixed;
    handleClose: (Event) => mixed;
    handleRequestPasswordRecover: (Event) => mixed;
};

function SigninForm(props:PropTy) {
    const {classes, submit, handleClose, handleRequestPasswordRecover} = props;
    const signinRef = React.createRef();

    const actions = [
        <Button
            type="reset"
            label="Reset"
            color="secondary"
            style={{ float: 'left' }}
            key='reset'
        >Reset</Button>,
        <Button
            label="Cancel"
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleClose}
            key='cancel'
        >Cancel</Button>,
        <Button
            type="submit"
            label="Submit"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            key='submit'
            autoFocus
        >Login</Button>,
    ];


    return (
        <form className={classes.form}
              onSubmit={submit}
              ref={signinRef}
        >
            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                <TextField id="username" name="username" autoComplete="username" autoFocus label={'Username'}/>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'baseline'}}>
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="password">Password</FormLabel>
                    <button className={classes.linkButton} onClick={(e) => {
                        handleRequestPasswordRecover(e)
                    }}>{'Lost password?'}</button>
                </div>
                <Input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    autoComplete="current-password"
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                label="Remember me"
            />
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'right'}}>
                {actions}
            </div>
        </form>);
}
```

The action that happens on "enter" is not "submit" as I expect - but rather the button's onClick event (`handleRequestPasswordRecover`). How do I redirect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `type` attribute of the button with the `onClick={(e) => { handleRequestPasswordRecover(e)...` to `"button"` (i.e. `<button type="button"...`).

The default type of buttons is `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside submit function you can call preventDefault();

> const submit = (event)=>{    event.preventDefault(); }

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below code in your html on **form** tag. So you can prevent the form submission on hit the enter key while focus on textfield.

```
<form className={classes.form}
          onSubmit={submit}
          ref={signinRef}
          onKeyPress={(event) => {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                   event.preventDefault();
                }
          }}>
```